# Why is the spark.implicits._ import not helping with encoder derivation inside a method?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, types, implicit

So, importing an implicit member from a created instance works as expected,

```scala
object Test extends App {
  class Bag {
    implicit val ssss: String = "omg"
  }

  def call(): Unit = {
    val bag = new Bag

    import bag._

    val s = implicitly[String]

    println(s)
  }

  call()
}
```

But, if I try doing the same with `spark.implicits._`

```scala
object Test extends App {
  val spark: SparkSession = ...

  def call(): Unit = {
    import spark.implicits._

    case class Person(id: Long, name: String)

    // I can summon an existing encoder
    // val enc = implicitly[Encoder[Long]]

    // but encoder derivation is failing for some reason
    // val encP = implicitly[Encoder[Person]]

    val df: Dataset[Person] =
      spark.range(10).map(i => Person(i, i.toString))

    df.show()
  }
}
```

It fails to derive the `Encoder[Person]`,

```
Unable to find encoder for type Person. An implicit Encoder[Person] is needed to store Person instances in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
        .map(i => Person(i, i.toString)
```

But, it works if I create the dataframe outside the method,

```scala
object Test extends App {
  val spark: SparkSession = ...

  import spark.implicits._

  case class Person(id: Long, name: String)

  val df: Dataset[Person] =
    spark.range(10).map(i => Person(i, i.toString))

  df.show()
}
```

Tested with Scala version `2.13.10` and `2.12.17` with Spark version `3.3.1`.

Comment: AFAIK it's more the `case class` definition being outside of the method than the dataframe

Comment: You are right... Another piece of knowledge. Don't use local classes unless explicitly required.

Comment: A general comment to put things into context. Serialization is hard, and in fact undecidable time to time, especially when you are trying to serialize functions like Spark. There are various very intelligent work out there on this but rather than dealing with this issue in depth, Spark made a set of rather arbitrary looking decisions to work around it. So it doesn't support the full set of features Scala itself offers. This is for example why, circe can auto derive a local class encoder but spark cant. Unfortunately these decisions aren't well documented and the error messages aren't helpful.

Comment: @sinanspd Yes, local classes just don't get a `TypeTag`. And Spark encoder derivation requires `TypeTag` because it also needs the serde which are being acuired by using reflection based on `TypeTag`.

Comment: @sarveshseri You can try to add TypeTag manually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494788/how-to-create-a-typetag-manually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473734/in-scala-2-12-why-none-of-the-typetag-created-in-runtime-is-serializable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73836319/scala-spark-encoders-productx-where-x-is-a-case-class-keeps-giving-me-no-ty https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74249859/spark-df-astype-fails-to-compile

Comment: Local `Person` has `WeakTypeTag`.

Comment: I submitted a PR to support local classes https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/38740

Comment: By the way, `weakTypeOf[Person] =:= weakTypeOf[Person]` and `symbolOf[Person] == symbolOf[Person]` are `false` https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/69tMXa7SR4iF30qmGqxfzg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already found out yourself, local `Person` doesn't have `TypeTag`. But it has `WeakTypeTag` (and `ClassTag`). Let's try to define `Encoder` for such class.

Naive approach with constructing `TypeTag` doesn't work

[How to create a TypeTag manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494788/how-to-create-a-typetag-manually)

[In scala 2.12, why none of the TypeTag created in runtime is serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473734/in-scala-2-12-why-none-of-the-typetag-created-in-runtime-is-serializable)

[Scala Spark Encoders.product[X] (where X is a case class) keeps giving me "No TypeTag available for X" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73836319/scala-spark-encoders-productx-where-x-is-a-case-class-keeps-giving-me-no-ty)

[Spark: DF.as[Type] fails to compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74249859/spark-df-astype-fails-to-compile)

```
implicit def ttag[A: WeakTypeTag]: TypeTag[A] = {
  val ttag = null // hiding implicit by name
  val wttagImpl = weakTypeTag[A].asInstanceOf[WeakTypeTag[A] {val mirror: Mirror; val tpec: TypeCreator}]
  TypeTag[A](wttagImpl.mirror, wttagImpl.tpec)
}
```

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: no Java class corresponding to Person found`

https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/41b7439d2e504e37f29b02e3500d24b1

Similar results is for

```
def typeToTypeTag[T](
                      tpe: Type,
                      mirror: api.Mirror[universe.type]
                    ): TypeTag[T] = {
  TypeTag(mirror, new TypeCreator {
    def apply[U <: api.Universe with Singleton](m: api.Mirror[U]) = {
      assert(m eq mirror, s"TypeTag[$tpe] defined in $mirror cannot be migrated to $m.")
      tpe.asInstanceOf[U#Type]
    }
  })
}

implicit def ttag[T: WeakTypeTag]: TypeTag[T] = {
  val ttag = null
  typeToTypeTag(weakTypeOf[T], mirror)
}
```

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: no Java class corresponding to Person found`

https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/c7a24abf1ff1011a1c87aa9d161d6395

```
implicit val personTtag: TypeTag[Person] = {
  val personTtag = null
  tb.eval(q"org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection.universe.typeTag[${weakTypeOf[Person]}]")
    .asInstanceOf[TypeTag[Person]]
}
```

`scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: reflective toolbox failed due to unresolved free type variables`

https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/6e35c0332f845fcd227d35ec49d4122f

This is how `Encoder[T]` is defined for `T` having `TypeTag`

```
implicit def newProductEncoder[T <: Product : TypeTag]: Encoder[T] = Encoders.product[T]

object Encoders {
  def product[T <: Product : TypeTag]: Encoder[T] = ExpressionEncoder()
}

object ExpressionEncoder {
  def apply[T : TypeTag](): ExpressionEncoder[T] = {
    val mirror = ScalaReflection.mirror
    val tpe = typeTag[T].in(mirror).tpe

    val cls = mirror.runtimeClass(tpe)
    val serializer = ScalaReflection.serializerForType(tpe)
    val deserializer = ScalaReflection.deserializerForType(tpe)

    new ExpressionEncoder[T](
      serializer,
      deserializer,
      ClassTag[T](cls)
    )
  }
}
```

Let's try to modify it for `T` having `WeakTypeTag` and `ClassTag`

```
implicit def apply[T: WeakTypeTag /*: ClassTag*/]: Encoder[T] = {
  val tpe = weakTypeTag[T].in(mirror).tpe

  val cls = mirror.runtimeClass(tpe)
  val serializer = ScalaReflection.serializerForType(tpe)
  val deserializer = ScalaReflection.deserializerForType(tpe)

  new ExpressionEncoder[T](
    serializer,
    deserializer,
    ClassTag[T](cls)
  )
}
```

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: no Java class corresponding to Person found`

https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/b58848fa6575b6fab0e9b8285095cc60

```
// (*)
implicit def apply[T/*: WeakTypeTag*/ : ClassTag]: Encoder[T] = {
  val tpe = mirror.classSymbol(classTag[T].runtimeClass).toType
  val serializer = ScalaReflection.serializerForType(tpe)
  val deserializer = ScalaReflection.deserializerForType(tpe)

  new ExpressionEncoder[T](
    serializer,
    deserializer,
    classTag[T]
  )
}
```

`org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable`

`Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: Main`

https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/0c86933f96e136d44fff555295ce01dd

So finally let's make `Main` extend `Serializable`

```
+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
|  0|   0|
|  1|   1|
|  2|   2|
|  3|   3|
|  4|   4|
|  5|   5|
|  6|   6|
|  7|   7|
|  8|   8|
|  9|   9|
+---+----+
```

https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/0e9b0bd2ed6237a4a1e1c40d620a9d88

So (*) is correct `Encoder`.

---

This doesn't seem to work with **generic** local `Person`

```
case class Person[T](id: Long, name: String, t: T)
```

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for Person$1`

https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/69496ce257fc9a3a7a5fbd004c52dcc0

`scala.ScalaReflectionException: free type Person is not a class`

https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/07bfe954dca677f0a39c06779b94280e

---

For generic local class the encoder should be (using both `WeakTypeTag` and  `ClassTag`)

```
implicit def apply[T: WeakTypeTag : ClassTag]: Encoder[T] = {
  val tpe0 = weakTypeTag[T].in(mirror).tpe
  val typeArgs = tpe0/*.dealias*/.typeArgs
  val tpe = mirror.classSymbol(classTag[T].runtimeClass).toType
  val tpe1 = appliedType(tpe.typeConstructor, typeArgs)
  val serializer = ScalaReflection.serializerForType(tpe1)
  val deserializer = ScalaReflection.deserializerForType(tpe1)

  new ExpressionEncoder[T](
    serializer,
    deserializer,
    classTag[T]
  )
}
```

https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/08c8f21ffb1427bfa15dd21fbdfb77fa

---

Well, now this doesn't work for a generic local class with type parameter that is a generic local class

```
val df: Dataset[Person[Person[Int]]] =
  spark.range(10).map(i => Person(i, i.toString, Person(i, i.toString, i.toInt)))
```

`scala.ScalaReflectionException: free type Person is not a class`

https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/5bceb2b81f2391c5c312a045edb827a8

---

Improved version of codec:

```scala
case class Application(tycon: ClassTag[_], targs: List[Application])

class DeepClassTag[T](val classTags: Application)
object DeepClassTag {
  def apply[T: DeepClassTag]: DeepClassTag[T] = implicitly[DeepClassTag[T]]
  implicit def deepClassTag0[A: ClassTag]: DeepClassTag[A] =
    new DeepClassTag(Application(classTag[A], List()))
  implicit def deepClassTag11[A[_], B1](implicit tycon: ClassTag[A[_]], dct1: DeepClassTag[B1]): DeepClassTag[A[B1]] =
    new DeepClassTag(Application(tycon, List(dct1.classTags)))
  implicit def deepClassTag12[A[_,_], B1, B2](implicit tycon: ClassTag[A[_,_]], dct1: DeepClassTag[B1], dct2: DeepClassTag[B1]): DeepClassTag[A[B1, B2]] =
    new DeepClassTag(Application(tycon, List(dct1.classTags, dct2.classTags)))
  // ...
  implicit def deepClassTag2[A[_[_]], B1[_]](implicit tycon: ClassTag[A[B1]], dct1: DeepClassTag[B1[_]]): DeepClassTag[A[B1]] =
    new DeepClassTag(Application(tycon, List(dct1.classTags)))
  // ...
}

def improveStaticType[T: WeakTypeTag : DeepClassTag]: Type =
  improveDynamicType(weakTypeOf[T], DeepClassTag[T].classTags)

def improveDynamicType(tpe: Type, classTags: Application): Type = {
  val newTycon = improveFreeType(tpe, classTags.tycon.runtimeClass)
  val targs = tpe.dealias.typeArgs
  assert(targs.length == classTags.targs.length, s"( $targs ).length == ( ${classTags.targs} ).length")
  val newArgs = targs.zip(classTags.targs).map((improveDynamicType _).tupled)
  appliedType(newTycon, newArgs)
}

def improveFreeType(tpe: Type, cls: Class[_]): Type =
  if (internal.isFreeType(tpe.typeSymbol)) {
    val typeArgs = tpe.dealias.typeArgs
    val typeConstructor = mirror.classSymbol(cls).toType.typeConstructor
    appliedType(typeConstructor, typeArgs)
  } else tpe

implicit def enc[T: WeakTypeTag : ClassTag : DeepClassTag]: Encoder[T] = {
  val tpe = improveStaticType[T]
  val serializer = ScalaReflection.serializerForType(tpe)
  val deserializer = ScalaReflection.deserializerForType(tpe)

  new ExpressionEncoder[T](
    serializer,
    deserializer,
    classTag[T]
  )
}
```

https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/56044515e031fcf1e977ab213013861d

---

`DeepClassTag` seems not to work with higher-kinded classes

https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/6388a437507e8389f30230e08382d9ff

Improved version but still not always working (there are too many shapes of type constructors)

https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/2625ee20695404c6fc118ab8680808f2

---

Instead of manual definition of type-class instances for different shapes of type constructors, the type class `DeepClassTag` can be defined with macros as follows

```scala
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox

case class Application(tycon: ClassTag[_], targs: List[Application])

class DeepClassTag[T](val classTags: Application)

object DeepClassTag {
  def apply[T: DeepClassTag]: DeepClassTag[T] = implicitly[DeepClassTag[T]]

  implicit def mkDeepClassTag[T]/*(implicit tCtag: ClassTag[T])*/: DeepClassTag[T] =
    macro DeepClassTagMacros.mkDeepClassTagImpl[T]
}

class DeepClassTagMacros(val c: whitebox.Context) {
  import c.universe._

  def findInstance[TC[_]](tpe: Type)(implicit wttag: WeakTypeTag[TC[_]]): Tree =
    c.inferImplicitValue(
      appliedType(weakTypeOf[TC[_]].typeConstructor, tpe),
      silent = false
    )

  def mkDeepClassTagImpl[T: WeakTypeTag]/*(tCtag: c.Tree)*/ : Tree = {
    val T = weakTypeOf[T]

    val tCtag = findInstance[ClassTag](T)

    val targCtags = T.dealias.typeArgs.map(arg => {
      val argInst = findInstance[DeepClassTag](arg)
      q"$argInst.classTags"
    })

    val targClassTags = q"_root_.scala.List.apply[Application](..$targCtags)"

    q"new DeepClassTag[$T](Application($tCtag, $targClassTags))"
  }
}
```

*(Is it working?)*

---

My PR to Spark to support local classes: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/38740

Answer (score 2):

The local `case class` is the reason for provided behaviour. Local class has so called **free type** and more about that you can check [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html#free-symbols). You may try to experiment adding `TypeTag` for `Person` in local scope to see it it may help.

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit more on the connection of free type and typetag pls?

Comment: Interestingly... I am not getting any compiler message despite having both `-Xlog-free-types` and `-Xlog-free-terms`.  Do these compiler flags even work in Scala `2.12.x` or `2.13.x` ?

Comment: @sarveshseri You can just call the method `isFreeType` https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/0fzp6dbiS4uvw9MuYcMw6A/3

Comment: @sarveshseri *"Do these compiler flags even work in Scala 2.12.x or 2.13.x"* https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/compiler-options/index.html  "`-Vfree-terms` or `-Xlog-free-terms` Print a message when reification creates a free term. `-Vfree-types` or `-Xlog-free-types` Print a message when reification resorts to generating a free type."

Comment: @DmytroMitin I think the `Person` `case class` in second example should be resulting in both free term message and a free type message. Or at least one of these. But I am not seeing any.

Comment: @sarveshseri Pay attention to the word "reification" in these settings description I quoted. These settings are for debugging reification i.e. `reify{...}` or qusiquote `q"..."` in macros (or maybe also runtime toolbox-generated ASTs), not in ordinary code.

Comment: @sarveshseri In ordinary code you can try the runtime-reflection method `isFreeType(..)` that I mentioned (maybe something about terms too). Or you can try these settings in reified code.

Comment: @sarveshseri For example without `-Xlog-free-types` in the following code https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/1xt3JhbPQLGP9zyddhAdyw/7 the macro doesn't produce warnings but the code calling the macro doesn't compile (`Macro expansion contains free type variable Person2 defined by myMacroImpl in main.scala:12:16. Have you forgotten to use c.WeakTypeTag annotation for this type parameter? If you have troubles tracking free type variables, consider using -Xlog-free-types`).

Comment: @sarveshseri But with `-Xlog-free-types` the macro itself produces a warning https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/1xt3JhbPQLGP9zyddhAdyw/8 (`free type: Ident(TypeName("Person2")) defined by myMacroImpl in main.scala:14:16`)

Comment: @sarveshseri Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38205671/scala-reflective-toolbox-failed-due-to-unresolved-free-type